# Are there any tools to optimize the number of consumer and producer threads on a JMS queue?

Tags: performance, multithreading, jboss, jms

I'm working on an application that is distributed over two JBoss instances and that produces/consumes JMS messages on several JMS queues.

When we configured the application we had to determine which threading model we would use, in particular the number of producing and consuming threads per queue. We have done this in a rather ad-hoc fashion but after reading the most recent columns by Herb Sutter in Dr Dobbs (in particular [this one](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/211800538)) I would like to size our threads in a more rigorous manner.

Are there any methods/tools to measure the throughput of JMS queues (in particular JBoss Messaging queues) as a function of the number of producing/consuming threads?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really about a specific tool, but may be helpful.

**Consumers:**

Not sure what your inner architecture is, but let's assume it's an MDB reading in messages. I assert that your only requirement here for rigorous thread count sizing is to choose a maximum cap. If your MDB uses resources from a finite supplier like a JDBC connection pool, consider the maximum cap as the highest number of concurrent instances from that resource that you can tolerate taking. If the MDB's queue is remote, you probably want to consider remote connections (or technically, JMS sessions) a finite resource. If the MDB has less finite requirements (and the queue is local), your maximum cap becomes the number of threads, memory used and/or flat out CPU consumed by the working threads. The reasoning here is that the JBoss MDB container will simply keep allocating more MDB instances (and therefore threads) until the queue is empty or the maximum cap is reached. The only reason I can think of that you would really agonize over the minimum would be if the container's elapsed time or overhead to create new instances is above your tolerance and those operations are usually pretty small potatoes.

**Producers**

A general axiom of messaging is that producers nearly always outperform consumers. You would think this is pretty arbitrary, but it is a pattern I see recurring all the time, even in widely different messaging scenarios. Anyways, it's tough to say how the threading should work for the producer without knowing a bit about the application, but are you basically capable of [indefinitely] proportionally increasing the number of producer threads and the number of messages generated, or do you have some sort of cap where additional threads simply do not generate more messages ? I would guess it is the latter since most useful work has some limited data or calculation supplier. As I see it, the two drivers here are ordering and persistence.

First off, if you have strict message ordering where messages must be processed in strict (FPFP) First Produced First Processed then you're in a bit of a bind because you almost have to drop down to single threaded throughput unless you can devise some form of logical message demarcation (eg. a client number where any given client's messages are always sent to the same queue, but you may have multiple queues each serviced by one thread so each client is effectively FPFP).

Ordering aside, persistence is the next consideration in that if you have reliable and extensive message persistence, (or have a very high tolerance for message loss) just let the producer threads go to town. The messages will queue up reliably and eventually the consumers will [hopefully] catch up. However, if your message persistence message count or simple queue depths can potentially give you the willies when they get too high, here's where a tool might come in useful. If your producer thread count can be dynamically modified (which they can in many Java ThreadPool implementations) then you could sample the queue depths and raise or lower the producer thread count in accordance with the queue depth ranges you define, optionally to the point where if the consumers basically stall, so will the producers. I do not know of a specific tool that does this but between two JBoss servers this is fairly simple to whip up. Picking your queue depth-->producer thread count will be trickier.

Having said all that, I am going to actually read the article you linked to.....

Answer (score 0):

I've got the perfect thing for you: IBM provide a free [command line tool called perfharness](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=1c020fe8-4efb-4d70-afb7-0f561120c2aa).

It's aimed at benchmarking JMS providers, i.e. measuring the throughput of queues (single or multiple) given different numbers of producing or consuming threads.

Some features:

- Send and consume messages at a fixed rate (msg/s) or at maximum rate possible on the queue
- Use a specific number of threads
- Use either JMS or native MQ
- Can use data either generated randomly or taken from a file
- Generates statistics telling you exactly how fast your queue is performing

The only down side is that it's not super intuitive, given the number of operations it supports. And IBM haven't open sourced it, which is a shame. However it sounds perfect for your purposes.